# Is type casting to super class and calling an overriden method acceptable? (Java)

Tags: java, types, casting, overriding, super

It seems to work but is it concidered 'good' programming?

Here is an example to clarify:

```
public class foo{
   foomethod(){do something};
}

public class foo1 extends foo{
    @override foomethod(){do something};
}

public class foo2 extends foo{
    @override foomethod(){do something};
}

ArrayList x /*with foo1 and foo2 objects*/
for (Object o : x){((foo)o).foomethod();}
```

is this concidered 'good' programming and if not what is a nice compact alternative?
(apart from switch(o.getClass()) if possible)

edit because I am really bad at clarifying it seems :)

I do mean to call the method that has been overriden and not the super method.
An alternative method for what I want to do would be:

ArrayList x /* again with foo1 and foo2 objects*/

```
for (Object o : x){
    switch(o.getClass()){
        case foo1.class:
            ((foo1)o).foomethod();
            break;
        case foo2.class:
            ((foo1)o).foomethod();
            break;
    }
}
```

but I want to avoid the switch statement because it makes the code much bigger and complex.

Comment: Well, if your software is designed well, you should never need to do that.  The whole point of overriding the method is because an object should have a different function if it is a subclass of the superclass.

Comment: *"I do mean to call the method that has been overriden and not the super method."* - This does not make sense.  The method in the superclass IS the overridden method!!

Comment: I know, some things are hard to communicate in a language other than your first, sorry, I mean to call the method that has overriden the super method, does that make sence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to work but is it concidered 'good' programming?

Modulo the problem with the wording of your question ...

Yes, it is good programming to declare a method in a superclass, override it in a subclass, and call it polymorphicly.

It is certainly much better than using a chain of `instanceof` tests or a `switch` on the class name.  Those approaches are considered "bad" ... because they involve wiring too much knowledge of the class hierarchy into other code.  For instance, if you add another subclass of `Foo`, all of those switches need to be checked and potentially changed.  (And the compiler won't remind you to do it ...)

Comment: Thanks, and again all sorry if the point of my question (which was exactly this) was hard to get because english isn't my first language. I have to set this answer as the accepted one because it's exactly to the point but thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Whether it's considered acceptable or not is entirely beside the point. The real problem is that it doesn't do what you seem to think it does. It doesn't 'call an overridden method'. The derived class's method is still called. If you want to call the overridden method, you have to use the super keyword from within the derived class.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I do mean to call the method of the extended class not the super class's method.

Comment: In that case what you're doing is one of only two choices, the other being to use Generics, so again your question is futile.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use Generics:

```
public class Foo{
   public void fooMethod(){ System.out.println("Foo");};
}

public class Foo1 extends Foo{
    @Override public void fooMethod(){System.out.println("1");};
}

public class Foo2 extends Foo{
    @Override public void fooMethod(){System.out.println("2");};
}

...

List<Foo> x = new ArrayList<Foo>();
x.add(new Foo1());
x.add(new Foo2());
x.add(new Foo());

for (Foo o : x){ o.fooMethod();}
```

Output would be:

```
1
2
Foo
```

Comment: +1.  There's no need for casting at all, if you do this properly.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I'm doing in my code practically, so I suppose there are no problems/objections with practically typecasting Foo1 and Foo2 to Foo and calling the overriden method. If I haven't missed something then thanks this should be it :)